Trouble understanding Complex analysis by Freitag and Busam theorem 1.5.11.

Theorem I.5.11 Let $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open rectangle, whose sides are parallel to the coordinate axes. Let $u: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a harmonic function. Then there is an analytic function $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with real part $u$.
The function $f$ is uniquely determined up to a purely imaginary constant. The harmonic function $v: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f=u+\mathrm{i} v$ is called a conjugate harmonic function to $u$. It is uniquely determined up to an additive real constant. (The theorem is true more generally for "simply connected" regions $D \subset \mathbb{C}$; see also the remark at the end of II.2, and Appendix C to Chapter IV.)
Proof of I.5.11. Let
$$
D=] a, b[\times] c, d[\quad \text { with } \quad a<b \text { and } c<d
$$
We choose two points
$$
\left.x_0 \in\right] a, b\left[\quad \text { and } \quad y_0 \in\right] c, d[
$$
From the equation $\partial_1 u=\partial_2 v$ follows that, for each $\left.x \in\right] a, b[$,$$
v(x, y)=\int_{y_0}^y \partial_1 u(x, t) d t+h(x)
$$
From Leibniz's rule the integral is differentiable as a function of $x$ and we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial_1 v(x, y) & =\int_{y_0}^y \partial_1^2 u(x, t) d t+h^{\prime}(x)=-\int_{y_0}^y \partial_2^2 u(x, t) d t+h^{\prime}(x) \\
& =\partial_2 u\left(x, y_0\right)-\partial_2 u(x, y)+h^{\prime}(x)
\end{aligned}
$$
and therefore
$$
h^{\prime}(x)=-\partial_2 u\left(x, y_0\right)
$$
This suggests to try following:
$$
v(x, y):=\int_{y_0}^y \partial_1 u(x, t) d t-\int_{x_0}^x \partial_2 u\left(t, y_0\right) d t
$$

Then the next remark is that: the function
$u(x, y) := \log (x^2 + y^2)$
is a harmonic function in the entire region $\mathbb{R}^2 \ {(0, 0)} = \mathbb{C}^0$. However, there is no analytic function $f : \mathbb{C}^0 \to  \mathbb{C}$ with
$\Re f(z) =  \log (x^2 + y^2) = \log |z|$ ,
since $f$ would have to agree in the plane slit along the negative real axis
with Log z, up to an additive constant. But then $f$ could not be continuous
at the points of the negative real axis. Theorem I.5.11 therefore is not true
I don't understand if this theorem is wrong or not, If it was wrong then why it was introduced as a theorem? also where in its proof is the mistake. secondly I don't understand the bold statement, I tried my best to understand it but I can't get what they are talking about. If this theorem is true then why does it have a counterexample?

The theorem requires $D$ to be an open rectangle, but $\mathbb{C} \setminus {(0, 0)}$ is not an open rectangle. This is why the example is not a counterexample to the theorem.

The proof of the theorem in the case of the example already fails when choosing $x_0$ and $y_0$.

@Smiley1000 Can you explain to me the statement in the bold?

Do you know what the function $\operatorname{log} z$ looks like on the complex plane slit along the negative real axis? Do you understand why it does not admit a continuous extension to the whole complex plane?
